# Was Adam capable of procreation in Genesis 2:7,8?

Tags: genesis, creation, adam

> “then the Lord God formed the man of dust from the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living creature. And the Lord God planted a garden in Eden, in the east, and there he put the man whom he had formed.”
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭2:7-8‬ ‭

When God made man/Adam, did God make Adam complete with all the parts necessary to procreate seeing he had no one to procreate with? Eve was made later from man

> “Then the Lord God said, “It is not good that the man should be alone; I will make him a helper fit for him.””
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭2:18‬ ‭

Comment: Anything in particular that makes you think he wouldn't be, aside from the lack of a mate?

Comment: Because this is used to argue that heavenly beings because they don’t have female counterparts therefore don’t have the equipment to procreate @curiousdannii

Answer (score 0):

New American Standard Bible
Genesis 1:

> 26 Then God said, “Let Us make mankind in Our image, according to Our likeness; and let them rule over the fish of the sea and over the birds of the sky and over the livestock and over all the earth, and over every crawling thing that crawls on the earth.” 27So God created man in His own image, in the image of God He created him; male and female He created them. 28God blessed them; and God said to them, “Be fruitful and **multiply**, and fill the earth, and subdue it; and rule over the fish of the sea and over the birds of the sky and over every living thing that moves on the earth.”

Both Adam and Eve were created on the sixth day. Adam might be a few hours older than Eve. It's likely that both were created to be capable of procreation (multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to clarify that this answer is based on personal thoughts and does not have scriptural verification.

**Adam was probably first created without a gender.** The name Adam, meaning "son of red earth", was first mentioned in Genesis 3:17, after Eve was created in Genesis 2:22. Before Eve was created, the Lord referred to Adam as "the Human", in Sefaria.org Hebrew-English translation, instead of "the man" as found in most English Bibles.

In most English Bibles, Eve's creation is described as being taken from the ribs of the man. However, in Sefaria.org Hebrew-English translation, it is described as being taken from the sides of the Human.

Now we know the human cells containing 23 pairs of chromosomes, and one pair determining the sex of a human. This microscopic knowledge was far beyond the comprehension of people in Moses' time. Based on Sefaria.org Hebrew-English translation, "Human" is used instead of "man", and "Sides" instead of "chromosomes", I would speculate that Adam was created without a gender. When the Lord decided "the Human" was not good to be alone, He created the marker in one pair of chromosome, each pair being a spiral thread-like structures tightly link **side by side**. Perhaps this is what "sides" meant.

After Eve was created, "the Human" became Adam, indicating that their gender was established. From that point on, human procreation became possible.

Comment: Considering all heavenly beings are masculine, it would make no sense to have an asexual being, especially since genitalia is not limited to copulation but also for other physiological needs.

Answer (score -1):

The Bible does not say. So aside from that ; would result in hypothetical assumption.

We know they conceived already. Normally we don't see God make something half way then augment it later.
Procreation by people takes more than just the parts. Knowledge for what to do and people to consciously agree.

Comment: its all that can be given for a superficial question. @NihilSineDeo

Comment: @NihilSineDeo you are assuming More interpretation into the statement " not good to be alone " than what the verse plainly said.  We know its not good to be alone from life lived.  But male and female were already present by day 6. For me its a non issue. Its one that if not careful you can make up things about in the mind not expressed in The Bible.

Comment: I gave your question a like by  way for at least trying. But not because it was a good question. : (